# load balancing with apache server 2.2

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, apache2, load-balancing

I ve got a problem regarding apache load balancing configuration.

Scenerio:
I have two identical worpress blogs

> localhost:8001/
>
> localhost:8002/

and one apache load balancer standing on `localhost:80`

//***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

the configuration of apache load balancer :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
```

`ProxyRequests Off`

`ProxyStatus On`

`#ProxyPreserveHost On`

```
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/

#ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/
```

## if I uncomment above line I will get a loop of redirections and an error GET / HTTP/1.1" 301

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember localhost:8001/ loadfactor=3
    BalancerMember localhost:8002/ loadfactor=7
   ProxySet lbmethod=request
</Proxy>
```

The problem is that apache load balancer make a redirection (adress uri changes from localhost =>localhost:8001 or
from localhost to localhost:8002 ). 
I would like to have only uri "localhost" (so uri of source is hided) on which I will find one of blog installed on  8001|2 port.

I tryied using rewrite module but it useless, it's making neverending loop. :(

Please, could you help me resolve this issue?

Comment: I've actually not been involved with Apache load balancing, but it seems odd your question yet has not been answered so I'll provide you with a link on the topic at least http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html

http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/188013/Load-Balancing-Using-Apache-s-mod_proxy_balancer

Comment: Hi, I read the article and the proxy balancer documentation but it doesnt help me a lot - the problem isnt which an algoithm should I use but how to remove redirection or how to hide a source URI from webbrowser. Please read an answer which I have just created. One way or the other thank U for you re help.

Comment: What about this flag:         
ProxyPreserveHost On

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/graylog2/nPSU8FKZC7U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with "slashes" at the end of lines with BalancerMembers.

It should be :

```
            BalancerMember http://localhost:8001
            # WebHead2
            BalancerMember http://localhost:8002
```

Insead of

```
              BalancerMember http://localhost:8001/
            # WebHead2
            BalancerMember http://localhost:8002/
```

Be careful with the "slashes".

Answer (score 0):

More info to better understand the issue:

[image]

The webrowse effect:

[image]

Why loadbalancer is making redirections? Is it posible to hide source URI ?